# How do I make this image properly scale using css

Tags: css, image, text, responsive-design

So I have an image, more of a screen shot, but I am not sure what I should do to make the image scale. Should I export the text as some kind of SVG? I don't want to have to re-write the text, that doesn't seem to make sense to me in this context.

The image is:

[image]

What would you do to make it so the image will scale, the text is readable and life is grand.

I have never worked with an image that has text on it. I am sure the first step is to remove the text, but does that literally mean I recreate the text with a bunch of spans and divs to get the colors? Or is there an easier way?

#### Update

Some people might not be clear as to what context of scaling I mean. I am talking web responsive.

That is scaling the browser. Right now the image sort of scales, how ever the text is unreadable.

Comment: Make the image scale? What do you mean?

Comment: Responsive design. ON a responsive web site. The image should scale, the text should remain legable. Whats the easiest way to approach this.

Comment: Scaling an image = resizing an image. I.e. all pixels get scaled equally much and the proportions (i.e. aspect ratio) stay the same. But of course you can scale the image and just show the left side on a smaller screen, if there's nothing of value on the right side.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7d064qao/

I hop this answers your question, wasn't sure what you meant

Comment: If you're not sure, ask questions in comments and then answer after you are sure. But I'm pretty sure this is not what he wants. Would you imagine that text remains legible this way?

Comment: this works if I remove the text from the image. Accept .... the text is apart of the image and no so easy to remove. So is there away to keep the image as is and scale it. I can just do width: 100% but then the text doesnt scale properly it seems so stretched and distorted

Comment: @KyleAdams This was what you wanted? I didn't think so.

Answer (score -2):

I'd set the image as a background-image of a div and use CSS to make the div itself responsive--width: __% or auto, etc. The background-image attributes are pretty flexible: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp.